# Europe sub-national urban rates

Tags: data, statistics, census, europe

Urban rate (the % of population living in urban areas) is a rather common demographic indicator, at nation-level resolution.
I'm trying to locate sub-national urban rate data ([NUTS level 2](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/statistics_explained/index.php/Glossary:NUTS) to be precise)

The raw data is accessible more or less in country census data, yet appears in a plethora of languages and sources.

Does anyone know of a source for urban rates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more source of disaggregated European population data: http://www.efgs.info/data/geostat/open-data/AIT_Grid_ETRS89-LAEA_1K_POP_EU27_2006.7z/view

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything so specific but there is the [Population density disaggregated with Corine land cover 2000](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/population-density-disaggregated-with-corine-land-cover-2000-2) dataset which:

> values correspond to density in inhabitants/km2. to obtain the
>   estimated population in a polygon, divide the sum of pixel values by
>   100.

If you have the lvl2 polygons I think you should be able to extract what you need
[image]